# Using typelevel/cats flatTraverse for different Functors

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scala-cats

I have been trying to use more abstract functional programming concepts like those from typelevel/cats for Scala.

In this specific case I am trying to eliminate the need to call `map(_.flatten)` after traversing some `Future`s.

Using the standard library it would look something like this:

```
def stdExample[T](things: Seq[T]): Future[Seq[T]] = {
  Future.traverse(things)(futureMaybeThings[T]).map(_.flatten)
}
def futureMaybeThings[T](thing: T): Future[Option[T]] = ???
```

I tried using `flatTraverse` from typelevel/cats but the best I could get was this:

```
def catsExample[T](things: Seq[T]): Future[Seq[T]] = {
  things.toList.flatTraverse(futureMaybeThings[T](_).map(_.toList))
}
```

The call to `things.toList` is required to get the Traversable, I can live with that one.

Since `flatTraverse` requires `f` to be `C => G[F[B]]` (where both `C` and `B` are `T`, `G` is `Future` and `F` is `List`), `futureMaybeThings` doesn't match without first transforming the result with `map(_.toList)`. This ends up being worse than the other solution.

It is possible to create a function that works just on `Future` and `TraversableOnce` (since there is an implicit conversion for `Option[A] => TraversableOnce[A]`. Such an implementation might be like:

```
def flatTraverse[A, B[_], C, M[X] <: TraversableOnceWithFlatten[X, M]](in: M[A])
                                                                (fn: A => Future[B[C]])
                                                                (implicit cbf: CanBuildFrom[M[A], B[C], M[B[C]]],
                                                                 asTraversable: B[C] => TraversableOnce[C],
                                                                 executor: ExecutionContext): Future[M[C]] = {
  Future.traverse(in)(fn).map(_.flatten)
}
```

This now works how I want:

```
def customExample[T](things: Seq[T]): Future[Seq[T]] = {
  flatTraverse(things)(futureMaybeThings[T])
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this same thing with typelevel/cats?

Bonus: If not then what would the signature of such a function look like?

Comment: Since `flatTraverse` is basically `traverse` followed by a monadic join (note that it requires a `FlatMap` instance for `F`), the concept only makes sense when using the same `F` for both the inner and outer container. One way to make this more generic is to provide a conversion function from the inner to the outer container, e.g. in the form of a typeclass. But I don't know if this is really necessary, IMO the code in the `catsExample` function is already quite usable.

Comment: Original `flatTraverse` actually works in that use case since `cats` 2.3 and while using either `scala.collections.immutable.Seq` or Scala 2.13 where it became the default `Seq`. Also note that using `Future` with `cats` is broken beyond repair for time being, and it's officially recommended in the docs to use `cats-effect`'s `IO` instead.